# Pathfinding on multiple grids connected through teleports

Tags: path-finding

I try to create a "AI" that can move independently on a map structure where the individual maps are only connected by one directional teleport squares (links).
There are some map areas you can only traverse if you fulfill some requirements. 
(for example you could be too heavy to swim.)
Movement is limited to 4 directions.

So far I use A* to navigate on a single map.
For the shortest path across multiple maps I came up with a pre-generated graph.
I use the links as nodes and search with Dijkstra because I wasn't able to come up with a working heuristic for that (no spatial arrangement of the links).
I generate the graph by calculating the cost for every link target square to all other links on that map. (tons of A* searches per map, takes 8-10 minutes to complete).

Then, for an actual search, I temporarily inject the start and end-point as links into the multi-map-graph (and do the cost calcing using A* without persistently saving it) so I can find the fastest way to the goal.
I get a list of goals, one goal per map out of that and just need to do an A* search for each goal on the corresponding map.

The tricky part in my approach is that the costly pre-calculated data isn't able to reflect the dynamic conditions for example swimming. (sometimes there is a completely different route necessary.)

**Now on to my question(s).**
Is there a known solution to this combination of problems that I'm just unable to find?
Has anyone already faced something similar?

There are some conditions that I want to meet. I'm already almost at the memory(ram) limit (that I'm willing to sacrifice) and I want to keep the disk IO as small as possible (multiple ai would be kill).
I thought about just pre-calculating path for every possible condition and at the moment that could actually work but I'm 99% sure that this wouldn't work in the future (because the size grows exponentially).

Comment: What's the density of your grid. Why not do astar at runtime

Comment: I do A* at Runtime. but only per map. As I said I don't know a heuristic to use across multiple maps. there are roughly 1000 maps (will be at least up to 5k in the future), 200x200 each. I would need to search with Dijkstra. that takes up 20 seconds for a single path. that's not acceptable. ram usage would explode too."I get a list of one goal per map out of that and just need to do an A* search and walk that for every element."

Comment: Use two tier HPAstar its a  hierarchical approach. It's designed for your situation.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand my explanations but I don't know how to describe it better. If it would be so easy I had no reason to ask. If I calculate a path respecting the "dynamic" parts I'm guaranteed to get a valid path to the end. There is no problem with early path invalidation (the problem that HPA* adresses)

Comment: I will try to draw a sketch tomorrow to better show what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure how your portals are connected, 1-1 or n-n? in case of 1-1 how about something similar to routing tables for your heuristics? A map would have connections (portals) that link it to another map, so a portal connects to all of the portals on both of your maps, build a table or query on each run the distance between portals as your heuristic and you are good to go. Querying could be done with dijkstra or A* if you use the avarage distance between portals as a heuristic. If each portal connects to each other portal the problem seems trivial

Comment: that's exactly what I currently do but the heuristics could get invalid if something "dynamic" blocks a path on one map. that's exactly the problem I'm describing in my question. I only can ask you kindly to read my question in more detail.

Comment: Use waypoints. And for your Dynamic conditions. You will have to calculate and store waypoints at certain intervals. So that ai can navigate using waypoints instead of expanding each node. For instance you want to go from A to D you would go from A - B - C - D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic paths, the [D* family of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*) is a good place to start. It is very similar to A*, but whereas A* must be completely recalculated whenever the shortest path changes, D* can incrementally recalculate only those parts that are affected by the path change. It can still be very expensive, e.g. if the path becomes blocked requiring a very long detour, but for minor path changes it is efficient.

But I've found that for the best performance, it is better to take as much advantage of your specific situation and make some non-optimal assumptions. [HPA*](http://aigamedev.com/open/review/near-optimal-hierarchical-pathfinding/) is a great example; it is non-optimal but is responsive and very fast. Try to do the same, like producing a graph made up of all the teleport ends, and assuming all the teleports within the same map are accessible, falling back to D* if they are not.

Comment: I found out about D* myself just days ago but in the end, my problem  was the language. Python. The time needed to traverse a node is just too big regardless of the algo. I learned quite a lot about graphs and their properties too and in the end, I think that the only real solution is a simplified/optimized graph (e.g. a QuadTree) but D* is the best tip so far on top of a full graph. I heard about hpa* a lot too but it just doesn't fit my problem because in my case the result would be quiet aweful without any kind of heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all available teleports per map containing information about their position and what map they link to, you could find out in a first step which teleport will bring you the closest to your target and then do a local A*-search to that chosen teleport.

Comment: I have over 1000 maps  and for some paths I need to travel through over 100 teleports. furthermore, how do I know if a teleport is close to my goal position if it doesn't bring me right to the correct map?